# How do you style an individual JQuery Autocomplete widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am not using a theme from JQuery UI Themeroller and I have the following:

**Along with the content of my .html file:**

```
<input id="autocomplete">
```

**At the end of my .html file:**

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
   source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
```

**I am attaching the following to my .html file, at the top:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>
```

My problem: I am trying to style that **specific** autocomplete widget (not **all** autocomplete widgets). How do I do this?

I've read through the JQuery UI documentation and all I can find is a solution for styling all autocomplete widgets, which is not what I want.

Comment: Just add a class to this particular autocomplete input and scope your css with this class.

Comment: When I do that:
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete().addClass("specific")
and I inspect the autocomplete ul, the class "specific" is still not in the list of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<div class="specific">
    <input id="autocomplete">
</div>
```

And at the theme downloader give it the css scope `specific`.

Comment: Do I really need to download a theme from ThemeRoller to make this work? I didn't do that, and now in my /css/ folder in the root JQuery UI download folder I have /no-theme/ and jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css and jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css

Comment: yes if you want to style it with themeroller you have to download a new theme with a custom css scope and include the css in your html.

Comment: That's quite unintuitive. Why not just allow one to "attach a class" or "register an additional class" when you initialize the widget [e.g.: $("#autocomplete").autocomplete()].

Comment: Because if you add a custom scope then the css file looks like this: `.specific .ui-state-default, .specific .ui-widget-content ...`. So the autocomplete must be child of an element with class `specific`.